# Find the cartesian equation of a line

Tags: vectors

Hello everybody I am doing an exercise but I'm stuck. I try to resolve it by finding the director vector of D' then the normal vector. Then determined the cartesian equation of D' which is: **D': x+5y=16**.  My idea next was to say that normal vectors of D and D' are perpendicular. But after that I realised my idea wasn't taking anywhere. Help me please. Thanks in advance.

Exercise: A(1,3) B(4,0) C(6,2)
 What is the cartesian equation of the line D which passes through point B and is perpendicular to the line D' passing through points A and C?

Comment: Do you know the vector $(a,b)$ is normal to the straight line $ax+by=c$ ?

Comment: Yes I know that. And c= ap1+ bp2 , with P(p1, p2) a point on D. Alright I kinda have an idea of the solution.let me test it and come back to you

Comment: $(a,b)$ is the required direction vector for the line perpendicular to $ax+by=c$. Since you're also given a point you can cookup the equation using these two:  1) Direction vector $(a,b)$, and 2) Point on line $(x_0,y_0)$: $$(x,y)=(x_0, y_0) + t*(a,b)$$
Good luck!